# Assembly Loading Version Mismatch: Why is it loading?

Tags: .net, assemblies, dll

I have two assemblies: HelloWorld.exe and Hello.dll. The exe is the main assembly and the dll is being used by the main assembly.

I compiled both HelloWorld.exe (1.0.0) and Hello.dll  (1.0.0). I placed the assemblies on a different folder.

I then changed the version of Hello.dll to 2.0.0 and proceeded to overwrite the Hello.dll 1.0.0 with the 2.0.0 version. I then launch HelloWorld.exe and it worked fine.

I expected it to crash and burn immediately because the referenced Hello.dll when I compiled the EXE was 1.0.0. Now, the 1.0.0 DLL has been replaced by 2.0.0 but it still worked!

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx):

> By default, an assembly will only use types from the exact same
>   assembly (name and version number) that it was built and tested with.
>   That is, if you have an assembly that uses a type from version 1.0.0.2
>   of another assembly, it will (by default) not use the same type from
>   version 1.0.0.4 of the other assembly. This use of both name and
>   version to identify referenced assemblies helps avoid the "DLL Hell"
>   problem of upgrades to one application breaking other applications.

Questions:

1. Why did it work?
2. How to make it NOT work?
3. BONUS QUESTION: What happens during the build process? Isn't the version of external dependencies hard coded to the main dependency?

**Note that Hello.dll is not strongly named.**

Here's the manifest for HelloWorld.exe:

```
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly extern Hello
{
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly HelloWorld
{
...//snipped
}
```

Here's the Assembly Binding Log taken from Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer):

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ian.uy
LOG: DisplayName = Hello, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/ian.uy/Desktop/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : HelloWorld, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/ian.uy/Desktop/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/bin/Debug/Hello.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\ian.uy\Desktop\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\Hello.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Hello, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from C:\Users\ian.uy\Desktop\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\Hello.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same thing and tried to look into the msbuild logs:

```
msbuild /v:detailed /t:build
```

The following lines looked interesting:

> Unified Dependency "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed".
>         Using this version instead of original version "7.0.0.0" in "C:\src\BindingTest\Lib1\bin\Debug\Lib1.dll" because AutoUnify is
>   'true'.

Additionally, If you check out resulting app.config file after the build, you would probably see automatic binding redirect there that your app.config did not initially have.

So the behavior we observe has to do with "[automatic assembly unification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)" and "[automatic binding redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2(v=vs.110).aspx)" msbuild processes.

Here is what [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad3f294.aspx) says about `AutoUnify` parameter:

> When true, the resulting dependency graph is automatically treated as
>   if there were anApp.Config file passed in to the AppConfigFile
>   parameter. This virtual App.Config file has a bindingRedirect entry
>   for each conflicting set of assemblies such that the highest version
>   assembly is chosen. A consequence of this is that there will never be
>   a warning about conflicting assemblies because every conflict will
>   have been resolved.
>
> When true, each distinct remapping will result in a high priority
>   comment showing the old and new versions and that AutoUnify was true.

Finaly, if you want to observe the "failure" you can call msbuild with following arguments:

```
msbuild /v:d /t:build /p:AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences=false;AutoGenerateBindingRedirects=false
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why did it work?

Because you have specified so ;)

> How to make it NOT work?

1. Rightclick on the DLL in *Solution Explorer*
2. Select *Properties*
3. Select *Use specific version*

> BONUS QUESTION: What happens during the build process? Isn't the version of external dependencies hard coded to the main dependency?

Not unless you specify so. It's off per default. Well designed assemblies should be backwards compatible and the version shouldn't really matter.

Comment: I ***think*** that a strong named assembly would work as you want.

Comment: I think so too. But what does "Use specific version" does if it doesn't really mean "use specific version"?

Comment: `Use specific version` only affects the compilation and not the loading at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> The runtime distinguishes between regular and strong-named assemblies for the purposes of versioning. Version checking only occurs with strong-named assemblies.

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-versioning)

Therefore, the answers are as follows:

> Why did it work?

Because the assembly isn't strong-named

> How to make it NOT work?

Make the assembly strong-named

> What happens during the build process?

Depends

- `Use specific version` = false: compiles against the first file matching the reference in the project, takes any version
- `Use specific version` = true: compiles against the first file found matching the reference including the specified version in the project

> Isn't the version of external dependencies hard coded to the main dependency?

Yes, the versions of referenced assemblies are hard-coded. You can verify this by using a decompiler (e.g. ILSpy) to read this information