# Can I load 2 versions of Newtonsoft.Json at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, json.net

I am using a CMS, proprietary, and trying to add the Google APIs for YouTube.

The CMS requires Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.  Google's APIs .NET requires Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.

I thought of trying to build a separate "webpage" for the YouTube upload and put it in an iFrame, but this will remove it from my form.  I don't see an effective way of doing that.

Can I somehow provide the proprietary CMS with the file it needs (and ships with) while giving the Google API the file it needs?

Comment: Why can the CMS not use 10.0?

Comment: AFAIK, not in the same AppDomain

Comment: @Jaxi because it is the worst piece of software I have ever dealt with!  :endRant: I am working to replace it, but it will be a few years worth of work.  In the meantime.... (FYI it's called RiSE and is part of iMIS)

Comment: Have you tried using [assembly binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) to force your application's dependencies to use the same version of `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks for the link, I think that has worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use 2 different versions of `Newtonsoft.Json`. Instead, you can use [assembly binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) to force your dependencies to use the **same** version.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.1.0" newVersion="11.0.1.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Reference: [Newtonsoft.json assembly package version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236342/newtonsoft-json-assembly-package-version-mismatch)