# Deploy VSTS build artifacts on Azure

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-deployment

I have build a DOTNET VISUAL STUDIO 2015 project on VSTS using the following tasks/agents..

> Nuget Installer,
>   Nuget Restore, Visual Studio Build, Publish build artifact

Although the build was successful, and the following artifacts were generated,

[image: Artifacts]

So i took the zip folder in this drop and tried to deploy on azure.

However there were issues in deployment on azure.

[image: Deploy Error]

Comment: What do you mean by *i took the zip folder in this drop and tried to deploy on azure*? What **specifically** did you do?

Comment: Check if there are multiple versions of the `Newtonsoft.Json` being used in your solution. You might need to add some binding redirects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236342/newtonsoft-json-assembly-package-version-mismatch

Comment: Also, do you have the same runtime error if you run the website in your local machine?

Comment: @DanielMann i mean i took the contents inside the [project-name].zip folder (the .dlls and web pages etc) and tried to deploy on azure cloud.

Comment: @RuiJarimba No there were no errors in the local build.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you shared *how* you tried to 'deploy on azure cloud'